# Java org.mockserver load response body from file

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockserver

is there a easy way to load the content of a file (like a Json file) for the response body from a org.mockserver?

Or do i have to do it in the usual way?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the json file contents using

```
public <T> T conversion(File jsonFile, Class<T> pClass) throws IOException {           
    return objectMapper.readValue(FileUtils.readFileToString(<your file>,"UTF-8"),<your class>);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can lookup in this post
https://github.com/mock-server/mockserver/issues/554

The approach is simply like you return a JSON data but you need to set the body similar this

```
"body": { "type": "BINARY", "base64Bytes":"XXXXXXXXX....." } }
```

Hope this helps.